# Servant print exceptions

Tags: haskell, servant

How can I print description of all exceptions? It would be great to toggle the debug/release format.

Standard Servant installation only shows `500/Something went wrong` which isn't really helpful

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Something went wrong
```

Upd:

I get the following error reporting my first handler:

```
Server.hs:152:31: error:
    • No instance for (MonadCatch
                         ((:<|>) (Servant.Handler (Map.Map String String))))
        arising from a use of ‘catch’
    • In the expression:
        server `catch` (\ e -> handleExceptions (e :: SomeException))
      In an equation for ‘serverWithExceptionsHandled’:
          serverWithExceptionsHandled
            = server `catch` (\ e -> handleExceptions (e :: SomeException))
```

The handler itself:

```
type API = "ping" :> Get '[JSON] (Map.Map String String) ...

ping :: Servant.Handler (Map.Map String String)
ping = return $ Map.fromList [("reply", "pong")]
```

Update:

```
server :: Server API
server = ping
    :<|> signup
    :<|> singin
    :<|> account
    :<|> getSessions


serverWithExceptionsHandled = server `catch` (\e -> handleExceptions (e :: SomeException))

-- | print to console and then rethrow
handleExceptions :: (MonadIO m, MonadThrow m, Exception e) => e -> m b
handleExceptions e = do
  liftIO $ print e
  throwM e

app :: Application
app = serveWithContext api ctx serverWithExceptionsHandled
        where ctx = checkBasicAuth :. EmptyContext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All server code runs in [`Handler`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-server-0.17/docs/Servant-Server.html#t:Handler) which has a `MonadCatch` instance as well as a `MonadThrow` instance. So you can warp  your server code with exception handlers like so:

```
handled :: Server SomeRoute
handled = server1 `catch` (\e -> handleExceptions (e :: SomeException))

type API = SomeRoute :<|> (other routes)

combined :: Server API
combined = handled :<|> (server code for other routes)

app :: Application
app = serve @API Proxy combined
```

where `handleExceptions` is your exception handler, for example:

```
-- | print to console and then rethrow
handleExceptions e = do
  liftIO $ print e
  throwM e
```

---

more examples:

```
ping' = ping `catch` (\e -> handleExceptions (e :: SomeException))

server :: Server API
server = ping'
    :<|> signup
    :<|> singin
    :<|> account
    :<|> getSessions
```

Comment: Thank you! Mind if I ask a question: I get the following error: `No instance for (MonadCatch  ((:<|>) (Servant.Handler (Map.Map String String)))) arising from a use of ‘catch’` How can I fix it? (See update)

Comment: @Nik what is your definition of `server`?

Comment: ah you have to specify exception handler for each server component separately

Comment: It turned out that servant prints all exceptions by default so with this handler I get `ThisException` printed to `stdout` twice. I need, however, to modify the default server response which still says `Something went wrong`. I think I should create a new question for this particular case to emphasize the difference.